# Map a unsecure IP or domain to https?

Tags: windows-10

I changed my router to connect to it securely using https://webname:8533 and installed the security certificate the router generated.

normally you could get to the login by local ip address or the generic router name. I tend to forget the secure path and port. Is there a way to map lets say http://192.168.0.1 to https://192.168.0.1:8533 or http://webname to https://webname:8533 ? Maybe using loopback some how?

Comment: Why do you not simply use a bookmark?

Comment: I'd look into putting a site on http://webname and have it rewrite urls, first from http to https, and second to your port. is this webapp running on your router itself, or an internal server?

Comment: This question can't be answered without knowing more about your particular router, so I'm voting to close.